# Error with joined use of SVMONO class and Babel Package

Tags: babel, sv-classes

I have a problem with the joined use of svmono class from springer link and the babel package. When I activate the babel package it produces the error:

"Missing \begin{document}. \newlabel{Einleitung}{{1}{1}}["

MWE:

```
\documentclass[graybox,table,envcountchap]{svmono} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Einleitung}
\label{Einleitung}
Test
\end{document}
```

However, no error is produced with the babel package excluded. Anyone experienced the same issue or has a solution?

[Link to SVMONO class I use](http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/125161/application/zip/svmono.zip)

Comment: I get no error from the example, only a warning about the `table` option, which is unknown to the class. Delete the `.aux` file and retry.

Comment: You are right it works. Actually I just realized, I downloaded the svmono class from the German Springer Site. Looks all the same, but produces the upper mentioned bug. But the one from the site provided with the link everything is fine! And it also contains the German expressions. So problem solved! Thx. for your reply! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've linked to an outdated `svmono` version. (Do complain to Springer for linking something outdated!) Springer is not very good at maintainig this class, but, anyway, as these lines are written, feel free to get an updated version 5.6 from http://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/resources-guidelines/book-manuscript-guidelines/manuscript-preparation/5636 .

You've also forgotten to use the class option `deutsch`.

With class version 5.6, the error occurs. Complain to Springer again; it's their fault.  (In my view, they bath in money from the libraries and can allocate a bit more of it to support LaTeX better.)  After complaining, comment out `ntheorem` stuff at lines 2036 till 2042, right after "SOPHIE TEMPLATE ENDS".  `ntheorem` has bugs and is outdated and nonmaintained since, I think, 2011. Removing `ntheorem`, you will have to deal with the consequence that labeling and referencing theorem-like environments will require more manual work, but this is a better option than failing compilation.

The only alternative I can imagine is that someone repairs `ntheorem` ...

Comment: Thanks for the link! This was actually the svmono class I was using and with this one it produces the error (after second compilation) mentioned above! So the old one works, the new one does not.

Comment: Thanks again! The solution works. I will suggest an update to Springer.

Comment: @kilsen Using a hacked class brings little if you have to submit the sources. The class file should be properly rewritten by Springer in first place.

Answer (score 1):

The awnser from Springer: “\usepackage{hyperref}” before the “babel” solves the problem.

```
\documentclass[graybox,table,envcountchap]{svmono} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Einleitung}
\label{Einleitung}
Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that in `hyperref.pdf`, file dated 2018-11-30, document dated September 2018, in §5.26 `babel` is loaded *before* `hyperref`.